# Is this a good Use Case diagram? UML

Tags: class, uml, case, diagram

I'm not sure my Use Case diagram is correctly written or it needs more data? I'm creating a web application for a restaurant. You should be able to:

- Add reservations
- Dashboard for making orders
- Dashboard for the kitchen
- Dashboard for the bartender
- Dashboard to edit menu.

The one who can make a class diagram for me will receive 20$ paypal.

Thanks. :)

[image: UML Use Case diagram]

Answer (score 0):

What are these dependencies stereotyped *return* ? That does not exist in the norm

Is the arrow is missing or hidden for the *extend* ?

---

yes you can replace the `Reservate ---<<return>>---> XX reservation` by `Reservate <---<<extend>>--- XX reservation` but this is not very clear because when you enter a reservation you finally edit it

Seems better to have

- enter do not have edit nor delete but the exception *cancel*
- an additional UC "find reservation" having extends to delete or edit or print

Comment: The <<return>> should be <<include>>.

Comment: <<include>> are wrong, include means *mandatory* and you do not want to do enter *and* edit *and* delete for sure ;-)

Comment: So they are all extends?

Comment: @Patrick delete as an extend of edit is strange for me, better to have it extending open

Comment: I would suggest to not use extends at all, and be careful with includes. Do not fall into the trap of functional decomposition.

Answer (score -1):

You have three direct roles and one indirect
1. Client
2. Accounts
3. waiter
4. chef

1. Client eats food if there is drink then he drinks drink. He also places order. He also pays for food.
2. Accountant gets amount of food and beverages served. One for food and other for drink
3. Waiter receive order for food and beverages
4. Chef makes food and confirm order